# Can I block someone from sending emails from their Gmail account to mine?

Tags: gmail

I want to block all emails from a Gmail account that keeps bothering me to my Gmail account.

I can mark the messages as SPAM, however this does not “block” the messages since Gmail will deliver future messages to my spam folder.

The only way I know to force messages to bounce is to completely fill my Google storage (e.g. filling up Google drive) but this will bounce all messages not just the ones I want bounced.

I'd like a way to prevented the sender from emailing me in the first place.

Comment: I am not sure how blocking everybody is better then sending one senders email to spam.

Answer (score 2):

1. NO: You can't stop them sending a message since that happens on their account not yours.
2. NO: You can't stop Gmail from receiving the message on your behalf as that happens before it hits your account.
3. YES: You CAN decide what happens AFTER Gmail delivers it to your account using the options available in filters.
4. YES: You CAN use Google Apps Scripts to perform more advanced functions.
5. REPORT: Report a user violating Gmail's policies.

## Gmail Filter

### Delete Messages Filter

*This creates a filter that deletes messages from this user on receipt.
If you want to delete these messages on receipt rather than seeing them in SPAM or INBOX.*

1. Login to your Gmail account in a web browser.
2. Naviagte to the filters tab in Gmail settings: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters
3. Click on the **Create a new filter** link on that page.
4. Enter the information that uniquely identifies the emails you want to delete. e.g. put the person's email address on the **From** line. somebody@gmail.com
5. Once you have the identifying information in click the **Create filter** link
6. check the options that apply which in this case would be (a) **Delete it** and (b) **Never send it to Spam**
7. Click the **Create filter** button.

Note: Messages will be sent to your TRASH folder and permanently deleted in 30 days.  There is no way from the GMAIL filters to permanently delete messages.

## Google Apps Script

### Very Advanced

GAS is a way to perform all sorts of wonderful things in Google apps that aren't supported in the default Apps/GUI's.  However, it requires a little to a lot of programming knowledge depending if you are just duplicating someone else's code or doing something new.

GAS would allow you to permanently delete the messages (and all your other messages too if you make a mistake ;-)

## Report to Google

### Abuse

Google information on abuse: https://support.google.com/a/answer/178266?hl=en

### Phishing

Google info on reporting Phishing: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8253?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

If you use Chrome you can do it exactly the way you want (instead of using a complicated workaround) with this Chrome plugin:

https://blocksender.io/

It will optionally even send the other person fake error messages to make them think that your account has been deleted so they will stop trying to email you.

Comment: This is a silly idea.  A browser based plugin that relies on chrome browser (what happens on the mobile phone etc.?) so he can pretend he isn't deleting them automatically?  If he can identify for the pretend bounce extension he can configure a filter  that deletes them.  Same as the plugin exept the filter is native to gmail so just works always.   Pretend bounce messages?  Common.